# How to double video frames without any duplicate frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, framerate, windows

My video details : DV-PAL 720x576i , 25FPS , duration=20s , frames=500

I need to increase (double) the video frames without any duplicate frame.

I used the following commands to increase (double) frame rate of the video.

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -r 50 out.avi
ffmpeg -i in.avi -r 50 -filter:v setpts=2*PTS out.avi
```

But not works properly.

Please tell me How to double video frames without any duplicate frames?

**Note** : tool (ffmpeg or mencoder or etc.) and the duration and speed are not matter for me, Because I want to extract frames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -r 50 -filter:v "setpts=0.5*PTS" out.avi
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -r 50 -filter:v "setpts=N/50/TB" out.avi
```

---

If you want to *interpolate* new frames, use

```
ffmpeg -i in.avi -r 50 -filter:v "yadif,framerate=50" out.avi
```

`yadif` is a deinterlacing filter, which is needed since the framerate filter does not operate on interlaced media.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,But the output of both your commands has 500 frames.(I need to get 1000 frames without any duplicate)

Comment: I used this command to extract out.avi  :  ffmpeg  -i out.avi  -f image2 %d.png

Comment: See new command.

Comment: Yes I want interpolate new frames , but the new frames quality is poor , I need something like [this](http://jcornet.free.fr/linux/yuvmotionfps.html) ,But I think that is impossible by ffmpeg (? maybe I'm wrong) ,So I'll accept your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Try [slowmovideo](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/).